# Azure DevOps, unable to create pipeline due to insufficient AD permission

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a new pipeline in AzureDevOps. In the configure tab I choose `Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service` and select the appropriate values such as `Cluster name`, `namespace`, and etc..

When I click next, azure Devops tries to validate and create the pipeline but then it displays the following error :

> Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. Error: Insufficient
> privileges to complete the operation. Ensure that the user has
> permissions to create an Azure Active Directory Application.
> [image]

The error is self-explanatory and It seems like it tries to create an AD App behind the scene but the user doesn't have permission to do so.

After doing some research I have been lead to belive there are **two ways** to allow my user to be able to create such pipeline: (but maybe I am wrong)

1. In the `user settings` tab of AD Directory, enable the flag that says: "**Users can register applications**". This option does not work for me, since it then enable **everyone** to be able to create apps, and that's not what I want.

2. Allow my users to be able access **Azure Active Directory**. I believe if I be able to access The Azure Active Directory, I will be able to create App, however this option is also not possible due to the legal restriction for accessing Azure Active Directory.

Is there a way I can create pipeline in AzureDevOps without having to go through the two options I have described?

Comment: You might the need to Application Developer role to register an app. Please check below solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above error occurs when the user doesnot have the sufficient privileges to create an application in Azure AD. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation).

If you donot want to change `Users can register applications` to `Yes`, which allows any user in the Azure AD tenant can register an app. You will need to ask your administrator to assign you a proper administrator role that can create and manage all aspects of app registrations.

For example `Application Developer` role. See [available roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#application-developer) and [role permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#role-permissions).

> Users in this role can create application registrations when the "Users can register applications" setting is set to No.

Another workaround is to Create the [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#service-principal-object) with the user already having required permissions in Azure Active Directory. In this way, you will have to configure the pipeline manually without using the `Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service` pipeline template.

1,First you will need to create below service connections:

Create [Azure container Registry service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#dockerv2-only-supports-docker-registry-service-connection-and-not-support-arm-service-connection-how-can-i-use-an-existing-azure-service-principal-spn-for-authentication-in-docker-task) using the service principal.

Create [Kubernetes service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-kuber).

2, When creating a new pipeline, you need to select `Starter pipeline` in `Configure your pipepline` page. And then add the docker and kubernete tasks in your yaml pipeline. See the example [Build and push to Azure Container Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops), [Deploy to Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/deploy?view=azure-devops).

You can refer to below pipeline example, and change the variables and settings accordingly.

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:

  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'ACRserviceConnectionName'
  kubernetesServiceConnection: "kubernetesServiceConnectionName"
  imageRepository: 'nigx'
  containerRegistry: 'leviregistry.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  imagePullSecret: 'leviregistry8720a6c7-auth'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
          
    - upload: manifests
      artifact: manifests

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              kubernetesServiceConnection: $(kubernetesServiceConnection)
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
              
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              kubernetesServiceConnection: $(kubernetesServiceConnection)
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/deployment.yml
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifests/service.yml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a **Service Principal** with an existing user who already has the required AAD permission. And then Team can continue using the Service Principal account for managing Azure Resources.

Also, I see the similar thread over here: [Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366279/failed-to-create-an-app-in-azure-active-directory-error-insufficient-privilege)